# Simple Javascript Generate and Check Number

Tags: javascript

I write a simple code for a little game, but It didn't know why not work
"The game is to enter any number in the field and try to match it with generated code"
if it matched "You Win !" returned in the second 
or it returns to the user "You Loose !
Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var y;

        var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

        function Change_Random(){
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*30+1);
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<h1>"+(x<10?"0":"")+x;
        y = setTimeout(Change_Random,10);
        }

        function Stop1(){
        clearTimeout(y);        
        }

        function Check_num(){
        if(x == num)
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<h1>You Win !";
        else
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<h1>You Loose !";
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<br /><br />
<input type = "text" name="num" id="num" /><br />
<input type = "button" value="Start" onClick = "Change_Random();" />
<input type = "button" value="Stop" onClick = "Stop1();Check_num();" />
<div id="div1"></div><br />
<div id="div2"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can Help please?because I want to do it with other 4 divs , I mean to extend it.
I'm wait for your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `parseInt()` to convert the string to number and do compare, something like

```
  var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num").value);
  if(x == num)
```

**UPDATE**

Also define the `x` variable outside the function `Change_Random()`

```
var x, 
function Change_Random(){
   x = Math.floor(Math.random()*30+1);
 .....
}
```

**UPDATE2**

Another problem is you will have to get the value of `num` inside the `Check_num()` function

```
function Check_num(){
    num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value, 10);
    if(x == num){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<h1>You Win !";
        console.log(x);
        x = "";
    }   
    else{
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<h1>You Loose !";
        console.log(x);
        x = "";
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WY36g/7/)

Comment: Please have look updated answer.

Comment: thanks but the output didn't match always loose , I try to use `Math.floor(Math.random()*2+1);` but also not work , why guys?

Comment: Please have a look updated answer and demo.

Comment: thanks sir but when I press Stop the value is still in variable x, how can clear that value and start another one

Comment: Have a look updated answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I found you are very new to here, If you found this answer is useful and as you wanted, then you can click on the tick mark as a accepted answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work